# For the solubility of AB2, Ksp=[A][B]^2=x*(2x)^2. Why is (2x)^2 not considered double dipping?

Tags: equilibrium

For $$\ce{AB_2<=> A + 2B} $$

$$K_{\text{sp}}=\ce{[A]*[B]^2} $$

$$K_{\text{sp}}=\ce{[x]*[2x]^2} $$

For the term $$\ce{[2x]^2} $$

Why isn't this considered double dipping on B's behalf?

I.e. why isn't it just $$K_{\text{sp}}=\ce{[x]*[x]^2} $$ or $$K_{\text{sp}}=\ce{[x]*[2x]} $$

Why is B both multiplied by 2 and squared?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy, if you consider:

$$\ce{AB2 <=> A + 2B}$$

It's solubility equations would be:

$$K_{\text{sp}}=\ce{[A][B]^2}$$

That equation follows from the **law of mass action**.

If you consider the amount of A as $x$, wouldn't the amount of B be $2x$ obviously?

If your issue is with why it's squared, it's just the equilibrium law, it follows from law of mass action. You can't really argue why the square is there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand A is x and B is 2x. That makes sense. I just don't understand why B=2x and becomes B^2=(2x)^2.

I.e. B is already *2 of x because it has twice as many moles as A. But then B is also squared. I  know that is part of the formula for K values. But I don't understand why B gets both *2x and is also squared.

Comment: They **both** must be there. The square comes because of the equilibrium law, and the 2 comes because there's two B released for one A. It seems to be redundant, but its not.

Comment: Thanks Pritt. Is there a simple answer to why the equilibrium law requires it to be squared? Or is there a reference you can point to me? I think understanding that would solve my problem.